# Исчезают классы, добавленные через jQuery после перехода на другую страницу в меню навигации

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, navigationbar

Есть кнопка "Версия для слабовидящих", при нажатии на которую к параграфам, инпутам и т.п. добавляются классы, которые увеличивают их размер. Реализовано это через обработчик щелчка на jQuery.
Проблема в том, что когда при ВКЛЮЧЕННОМ режиме для слабовидящих нажимаешь на другую страницу навигации, она подгружается без режима для слабовидящих, то есть подгружается изначальная стандартная разметка без доп. классов.
Отсюда вопрос: Как изменить это поведение, чтобы режим для слабовидящих не исчезал ровно до того момента, как повторно не нажмешь кнопку для слабовидящих, а переход по страницам не менял это поведение?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы бы лучше к body добавляли класс, что исопользуется версия, и стили бы перекрыли для инпутов с этим родительским классом, а не просто ко всем полям добавляли.

при клике  в кнопку устаналиваете куки. на сервере класс к боди добавляйте по наличию куки. ну или в сессию или что там еще. Без сервер-сайта если делать, то при клике запоминайте это в storage. При открытии каждой страницы смотрите, и при неоходимости добавляйте ваши классы.

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <div class="switcher_section">
        <button class="normal">Нормальная версия сайта</button>
        <button class="notseen">Для слабовидящих</button>
    </div>

    <div class="text_section">
        <p>Lorem Inspum Dollar</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // Функция позваляет получать значения куки
    function getCookie(name) {
        let matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
            "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
        ));
        return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
    }

    // Переключатели версий сайта
    $('.switcher_section button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if($(this).hasClass('normal')){
            document.cookie = "what_version=normal";
            $('body').removeClass('site-version-notseen');
        } else {
            document.cookie = "what_version=notseen";
            $('body').removeClass('site-version-normal');
        }

        $('body').addClass('site-version-' + getCookie('what_version'));

    })

    // Это запускается после перезагрузки страницы
    var what_version = getCookie('what_version');
    if(typeof what_version != 'undefined'){
        $('body').addClass('site-version-' + what_version);
    }


});
```

**Css**

```
.site-version-notseen p{
    font-size: 26px;
}
```